# Proof of Replaceability of Equivalent Formulas by Structural Induction

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

My class discussed the following theorem for which I wasn't able to make it to class. Its proof is supposed to involve structural induction but I am stuck in the inductive step...

**Let B |=| C. If A' results from replacing some (not necessarily all) occurrences of B, in A, by C, then A |=| A'.**

So far I have:

We want to prove R (the property above) for all formulas X. i.e. R(X) for all formulas X.

Base Case: X is an atomic formula (one variable)
If X is the atomic formula x, and x |=| x', then X' is the formula x'. We conclude X |=| X'

Inductive Step: Assume R(X), and R(Y) for formulas X and Y.
???

The way I learned it, the inductive step involves assuming that some formulas have the property. We use this assumption to show that this implies

(X ^ Y), (X V Y), (X -> Y), and (-X)

i.e. 
R(X) ^ R(Y) -> (X ^ Y) ^ (X V Y) ^ (X -> Y) ^ (-X)

(Not sure about the above i.e., but that's what I think).

I'm having trouble with this step.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is |=| supposed to mean? Please use normal notation. The site uses MathJax (q.v.).

Comment: A |=| B means A is logically equivalent to B. i.e. A |= B and B |= A. |= means entailment. Sorry for teh confusion. Hope that helps

Comment: Oh ok. $\iff$ works too. That's \iff between dollar signs. |= is $\models$ i.e. \models. The connectives are \neg \lor \land \to and...  \leftrightarrow, quantifiers are \forall and \exists.

Comment: You can see this post: [math.stackexchange.com/questions/687180/proving-tautologically-equivalent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687180/proving-tautologically-equivalent).