# Prove of K ⊢ A ↔ B then K ⊢ C [A/q ] ↔ C [B/q ]

Tags: modal-logic

I am currently reading "Boxes and Diamonds: An Open Introduction to Modal Logic". Here is the PDF to the book: https://builds.openlogicproject.org/courses/boxes-and-diamonds/bd-screen.pdf

One of the exercises reads the following: **Prove Proposition 3.19 by proving, by induction
on the complexity of C , that if K ⊢ A ↔ B then K ⊢ C [A/q ] ↔
C [B/q ].**

Can someone please help me with proving this? I am just really curious how the proof actually would look.

[image: Proposition 3.19.]

Comment: See the post [Proving tautologically equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687180/proving-tautologically-equivalent)

Comment: Thank you, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Induction on $C$ means considering each possibility of $C$ as a formula, as given by Definition 1.2, and then applying the definition of substitution (1.4). For example:
$\newcommand{\K}{{\bf K}}$

1. If $C = \bot$ then $C[A/q] =\bot = C[B/q]$, so since $\K\vdash C[A/q]$ we know $\K\vdash C[B/q]$.
2. If $C = p$ is a variable, then either

   1. $p = q$, in which case $C[A/q] = A$, and $C[B/q] = B$, but since $\K \vdash A\leftrightarrow B$ then $\K\vdash C[B/q]$
   2. $p \neq q$, in which case $C[A/q] = C = C[B/q]$, so $\K \vdash C[B/q]$.
3. If $C = D \wedge E$, then $C[A/q] = D[A/q]\wedge E[A/q]$, but by the induction hypothesis, $\K\vdash D[A/q]$ implies $\K\vdash D[B/q]$, and similarly $\K\vdash E[A/q]$ implies $\K\vdash E[B/q]$, therefore $\K\vdash C[B/q]$.
   $$\vdots$$